# Initializing class object in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to learn classes in C++ but i'm unable to understand what's happening here.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

class Dummy{

    public:
        std::string name;
        void setName(std::string input){
            name = input;
        }
};

int main(){
    Dummy obj;
    obj.setName("John");

    Dummy obj1(); // error in this line
    obj1.setName("John");
}
```

Error:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:18:10: error: request for member ‘setName’ in ‘obj1’, which is of non-class type ‘Dummy()’
   18 |     obj1.setName("John");
      |          ^~~~~~~
```

Comment: `Dummy obj1();` is a vexing parse. It's a function declaration, not an object. Do `Dummy obj1{};` instead.

Comment: Im very new to coding and C++ please can you explain me in detail or link to a resourse would be great help @cigien

Comment: Linked to a dupe. That should address the question.

Comment: @cigien Thank you... I couldn't search it did not know what to search.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely not easy to search for something like this if you don't know what's going on :)

Comment: @cigien Understood why the error occurred but `Dummy obj1{};` works what's happening there.

Comment: That syntax unambiguously defines an object of type `Dummy`, which is what you want.

Comment: @cigien Thank you learnt something new and i found `{}` about this in cplusplus.com under uniform initialization.